# Need help with using fitch system for this proof: Given ¬q, (¬p⇒(¬q⇒¬r)), (s∨r), (s⇒t), and (p⇒t), prove t.

Tags: logic, solution-verification, proof-writing, propositional-calculus

I am having difficulty using the Fitch proof system for the following proof: Given ¬q, (¬p⇒(¬q⇒¬r)), (s∨r), (s⇒t), and (p⇒t), prove t. I'm able to use the following rules: Reiteration, Negation introduction, Negation elimination, And introduction, And elimination, Or introduction, Or elimination, Assumption, Implication elimination, Biconditional introduction, Biconditional elimination, Universal introduction, Universal elimination, Existential introduction, Existential elimination. I've tried by assuming ¬t, proving a contradiction and thereby deriving ¬¬t, and then using negation elimination to get t. I've also tried to prove r⇒t and then use or elimination to prove t. I have unfortunately not yet been able to prove t using these approaches. If anyone has any ideas for how I may go about solving this proof, I'd appreciate your sharing them with me. Thank you for sharing any thoughts you might have.

Comment: The only reason $r \to t$ can be proven is because $t$ can be proven in and of itself.... so this really doesn;t help in proving $t$.  I like your indirect proof method better: assume $\neg t$, and try and get a contradiction. Now, when assuming $\neg t$, you should be able to get to $\neg s$ and $\neg p$ given $s \to t$ and $p \to t$ respectively.  Do you know how to do that? To just focus on one of them, do you know how to derive $\neg s$ from $s \to t$ and $\neg t$?

Comment: Third time you ask it.